# If $A$ and $B$ are natural numbers such that $A-B = \dfrac{A}{B}$, what is the value of $A+B$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $A$ and $B$ are natural numbers such that $A-B = \dfrac{A}{B}$,  what is the value of $A+B$?

The answer is $6$. I tried all the basic maths functions but was not able to get it. I would like to know if its a trial and error based question or it can be derived.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have:

$A = B + \dfrac{A}{B}\implies AB - B^2 - A = 0$

$\implies A = \dfrac{B^2}{B-1} = B+1 + \dfrac{1}{B-1}$

$\implies B-1 = 1 \implies B = 2$

$\implies A = 4$

$\therefore A+B = 6$

Answer (score 2):

$A-B=\frac{A}{B}$, so, multiplying by $B$, we have $AB-B^2=A$, so $AB=B^2+A$.

Since $A$ and $B$ are natural numbers, we have $B \mid B^2+A$, so $B \mid A$. Write $A=CB$, then $CB^2=B^2+CB$, so $CB=B+C$, so $(C-1)(B-1)=1$, so $C=B=2$.

Hence $A=CB=4$ and since $B=2$, we also have $A+B=6$.